# How to work with the periodic agent in windows phone

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i am using a periodic agent in my app were i have to display the quotes at a frequency of 30min in a given interval  set by the user.In the invoke method below  i am reading the xml file to get the value of start time,end time and frequency and in  another try catch getting the xml file of quotes.
i want to call the invoke method after very 30 min to display Quotes..

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        TimeSpan minute;
        TimeSpan hour;

        try
        {

            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Reminder.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ReminderModel>));
                    List<ReminderModel> data = (List<ReminderModel>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

                    foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        //if (item.StartTime <=item.EndTime)
                        if (item.StartTime < DateTime.Now && item.EndTime >= DateTime.Now)
                        {
                            if (item.Frequency.TimeOfDay.Hours == 0)
                            {
                                minute = new TimeSpan(item.Frequency.TimeOfDay.);
                                // minute = new TimeSpan(item.Frequency.Minute);

                                item.StartTime.AddMinutes(item.Frequency.TimeOfDay.Minutes);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 hour = new TimeSpan(item.Frequency.Hour);
                                item.StartTime.AddHours(item.Frequency.TimeOfDay.Hours);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("The Periodic agent is stop");
                        }



                    }

                }
            }

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
        }


        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Notification.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        var Data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var value = Data.Replace("\r\n", "").Remove(0, 74).Split('<');
                        this.QuoteRemoveList.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in value)
                        {
                            if (item.StartsWith("QuoteElement"))
                            {

                                this.QuoteRemoveList.Add(item.Remove(0, 13));
                            }


                        }
                    }

                }


            }
        }

        catch
        { }


        {

            Random rd = new Random();


            string toastMessage = QuoteRemoveList[rd.Next(0, 99)];


            ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
            toast.Title = "Quotes";
            toast.Content = toastMessage;
            toast.Show();
            NotifyComplete();

            // If debugging is enabled, launch the agent again in one minute.
            //#if DEBUG_AGENT
            // ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            //#endif


                if (this.Agent.hour>0)
                {
                    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromHours(personalViewModel.Frequency.TimeOfDay.Hours));
                }
                else if (this.Agent.minute > 0)
                {
                    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(personalViewModel.Frequency.Minute));
                }
            }




        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from here([Background agents for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx)) yo can have Details how `Background agents` work in windows phone and from here([How to implement background agents for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx)) you can have guide for
How to implement background agents for Windows Phone 8. Before imeplementing Refer the guidelines and instruction from the first link.

Comment: sir i have read those article earlier and  then started working on periodic agent.my problem is after reading the xml file in first try catch block i'm getting the start time,end time and frequency i want the frequency in timespan.I try to convert it but it is not working i just need the frequency in timespan so that i can work further.

Comment: Periodic agents typically run for 25 seconds. There are other constraints that may cause an agent to be terminated early. Battery Saver mode is an option that the user can enable on the device to indicate that battery life should be prioritized. If this mode is enabled, periodic agents may not run, even if the interval has elapsed. so to set time interval or frequency by urself is quite tricky that it may run or may not be.